# How to return 401 ("Unauthorized") from AWS Lambda Authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

We are using AWS Lambda Authorizer with API Gateway to protect our downstream API's.

Below is the code snippet from our Java based lambda authorizer

```
Statement statement = Statement.builder()
            .resource(input.getMethodArn()).effect(effect)
            .build();

    PolicyDocument policyDocument = PolicyDocument.builder()
            .statements(
                    Collections.singletonList(statement)
            ).build();

    return AuthorizerResponse.builder()
            .principalId(userId)
            .policyDocument(policyDocument)
            .context(ctx)
            .build();
```

1. With correct token (effect = "Allow"): getting proper API response from API
2. With incorrect token (effect = "Deny") Getting 403 HTTP response code.

We need 401 ("Unauthorized") as a response, Can someone pls help how to do this ? we have lambda authorizer written in java.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw RuntimeException with Unauthorized message. One thing is to be in mind, you can not throw checked exception like Exception("Unauthorized"). Because **handleRequest** method signature of **RequestHandler** interface don't allow to do so.

```
if(isInvalidToken){
  throw new RuntimeException("Unauthorized");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing an exception with a message of "Unauthorized".